# How do you determine the dimensions of a widget?

Tags: android

I am trying to use the RemoteViews.setTextViewTextSize to set the size of the text of my widget dynamically.  I would like it so that it is proportional to the dimensions of the widget.

How do you determine the dimensions of a widget?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you, yourself put the dimensions of your `AppWidget` in your `XML` file. So you don't need to determine any dimensions! In the case of the resizable instance of widget you can't get dimensions!

Comment: Can you put some documentation on why we can't get the size of a resizeable instance?  Just in case it was changed in the latest API since the setTextViewTextSize was just added in JB.